# How to link to an external URL with LinkTo with HandelBars

Tags: frameworks, web, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am currently starting to learn to use Ember.js for web app development. Currently there is something quite basic which I have not yet been able to achieve. Link to an external url like www.google.com or whatever. This is what I have:

HTML

```
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div>
      Hello, <strong>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</strong>!
    </div>

      {{#linkTo google}}Google{{/linkTo}}

    </script>
</body>





$(document).ready(function() {



//alert("HELLO WORLD");
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    firstName: "Trek",
    lastName: "Glowacki",
    googleURL: "www.google.com/ncr"
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("google", {
        path: "www.google.com"
    });

});
```

});

When the link renders it does work but it goes to this address: E:/EMBERJS/index.html#/www.google.com

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. I can't believe I haven't figured this out on my own but a little outside help can't hurt.

Regards,

Ox

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need the `linkTo` template? Why wouldn't you just use an anchor tag in pure HTML?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't want to be using the `linkTo` helper for this. The `linkTo` helper is used for transition to other states within your Ember.JS application, whereas you're attempting to move people away from your application.

There are two methods you can use:

1. This will bind your `targetUrl` to your anchor, but it won't update if the URL is changed.

   `<a target="_blank" href="{{unbound view.targetUrl}}">Google</a>`
2. The next approach will bind to the anchor, and it will update that anchor accordingly if you update the `targetUrl` property on the object:

   `<a target="_blank" {{bindAttr href="view.targetUrl"}}>Google</a>`

Here's a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/zscff/

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle for you so you can understand the difference that `unbound` makes: http://jsfiddle.net/zscff/1/ We're changing the `targetUrl` property after 2.5 seconds, you'll see that the second example updates as expected, but the first one doesn't. They're both using the same property, but because we've specified the first property as `unbound`, Ember doesn't know how to update it in the DOM.

Comment: bindAttr is now deprecated in favour of bind-attr

Answer (score 0):

As it was said you don't need to use **link-to** helper.
You just need to use simple anchor tag `<a> </a>`.

I just had the same issue. In order to fix this you just need to be careful with anchor tag.

E.g. if you type link like this
`<a href='www.example.com'> example </a>`, Ember will generate the following link 
 **localhost:4200/www.example.com**

But if you add http, to href attribute everything is ok. 
`<a href='http://www.example.com'> example </a>`. 
Output is **www.example.com**

Hope it helps.